# Is the Laplace equation a special case of the wave equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let me get this straight. The Laplace equation, which is part of the definition of the concept of a harmonic function, is the partial differential equation $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$. Isn't that just a special case of the wave equation $f_{xx}=cf_{yy}$, namely when $c=-1$, and if so, then why does this special case have a name of its own?

Comment: The Laplace equation in 2D is $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0$. This is not a special case of the wave equation because in the wave equation $c$ is non-negative (you can see it written with a square on Wikipedia). The sign of that coefficient matters a lot and changes the behavior of the solutions substantially.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan So a harmonic function does not describe the propagation of a wave at all?

Comment: No. Are you familiar with any examples?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan The argument function is harmonic, I think, since it's the imaginary part of the logarithm function, which is holomorphic. So I'm familiar with at least one example.